# Разделение массива

Tags: c, массивы

Программа должна разделять массив на два массива, содержащие его чётные и нечётные значения.
Работает на небольших значениях, до 10, далее выдает чушь, скажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void append (int *arr, int *len, int elem)
{
    arr = realloc(arr, (*len + 1) * sizeof(int));
    arr[*len] = elem;
    *len = *len + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int len_ch = 0;
    int *ch = NULL;
    ch = malloc(len_ch * sizeof(int));

    int len_nch = 0;
    int *nch = NULL;
    nch = malloc(len_nch * sizeof(int));

    int N;
    int elem;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int a[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        //a[i] = 0 + rand() % 20;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            append(ch, &len_ch, a[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            append(nch, &len_nch, a[i]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

    printf("\nEVEN: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < len_ch; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", ch[i]);
    }

    printf("\nODD: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < len_nch; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", nch[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Что ты подразумеваешь под чушью?

Comment: Показать что на входе и выходе в случае с "чушью"

Comment: @nick_n_a Выдаются значения, которые я не вводил, либо нули.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну смотрите сами:

```
void append (int *arr, int *len, int elem)
{
    arr = realloc(arr, (*len + 1) * sizeof(int));
```

но это новое значение указателя остается локальным в функции, и при выходе из нее благополучно теряется...

Нужно

```
void append (int **arr, int *len, int elem)
{
    *arr = realloc(*arr, (*len + 1) * sizeof(int));
```

ну и соответственно, передавать в функцию указатель на переменную - типа

```
append(&ch, &len_ch, a[i]);
```

Comment: Тогда добавление элемента в конец массива будет выглядеть `*arr[*len] = elem ; ` ?

Comment: `(*arr)[*len] = elem;` - то, что вы написали - это присваивание `elem` по адресу в `arr[*len]` :)

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Ушёл доучивать указатели)